# matlab replace space character on fgets

Tags: matlab, newline, fgets

I'm using fgets to read lines from file to select specific lines to print into another file.

But i'm having some problem on deleting the space character that exists on the line gotten by the fgets and replacing it for a tab character.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What does "some problem" mean?

Comment: add relevant code and try to describe your problem a way, everyone can understand.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine exactly which character is the issue. The most common "space" character is [ASCII char code 32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart), but there are others. You can use `double` to determine the code for each of the characters in a string read in by `fgets`:

```
test_str = 'hello world!';
double(test_str)
```

which returns

```
104   101   108   108   111    32   119   111   114   108   100    33
```

Next you can use [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) to replace this with a tab (ASCII char code 9):

```
test_str = 'hello world!';
new_str = strrep(test_str,' ',char(9))
```

or using a non-standard whitespace:

```
test_str = sprintf('hello\fworld!');
new_str = strrep(test_str,char(12),char(9))
```

It is also possible to do this with [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html), but `strrep` is considerably faster even if you need to call it multiple times to replace different characters.

You may also find the [`isspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isspace.html), [`isstrprop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isstrprop.html), and [`deblank`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deblank.html) functions useful.